# Does Spring Data MongoDb support $filter array aggregations operator?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement in Spring Data using MongoTemplate the following working mongoDb query:

```
db.answers.aggregate([
        { "$match" : { "object_id" : "1" } },
        { "$project": { 'answer_list': 1, 'profile': { $filter : { input: '$answer_list', as: 'answer', cond: { $eq: [ '$$answer.question', 2 ] } } } } },
        { "$unwind" : "$profile"},
        { "$unwind" : "$answer_list"},
        { "$group" : { "_id" : { "question" : "$answer_list.question", "answer" : "$answer_list.answer", "criteria" : "$profile.answer"}, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },
        { "$sort" : { "_id.question" : 1, "_id.answer" : 1 } }
]);
```

The collection has this structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("..."),
"object_id" : ObjectId("..."),
"answer_list" : [ 
    {
        "question" : NumberLong(0),
        "answer" : NumberLong(0)
    }, 
    {
        "question" : NumberLong(1),
        "answer" : NumberLong(2)
    }, 
    {
        "question" : NumberLong(2),
        "answer" : NumberLong(2)
    }
]}
```

What I'm trying to do here is a report on a simple survey submission data. The question is "How did the users that answered 0 to the first question answer to the second question?"
I spent all day searching the SpringData Mongo Db docs but I found nothing.
Can anyone help?

TIA

Comment: I've created [DATAMONGO-1491](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1491) to add support for `$filter`.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I hope to find a workaround until it's implemented

Comment: As of Spring Boot 3 (maybe also Spring Boot 2.x) the `$filter` is supported. In the [AggregationTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/4c77763cd39abf2a2d7e199778016728b45d79fc/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationTests.java) class in the spring-data-mongodb repository you'll find some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can workaround this issue by providing your own `AggregationExpression`.

```
ProjectionOperation agg = Aggregation.project() //

      .and(new AggregationExpression() {

        @Override
        public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {

          DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
          filterExpression.put("input", "$answer_list");
          filterExpression.put("as", "answer");
          filterExpression.put("cond", new BasicDBObject("$eq2", Arrays.<Object> asList("$$answer.question", 2)));

          return new BasicDBObject("$filter", filterExpression);
        }
      }).as("profile");
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I need. The only problem is that interface AggregationExpression is not public, if I'm not missing something...

Comment: I've created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1492 suggesting that the interface should be public. I'm still searching for a way to implement your suggestion...

Comment: doh... my bad - that one should be public - thanks for filing the issue! Since `AggregationExpression` is package private you could add the package `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation` to your project and create a public class/interface `FilterExpression` implementing/extending `AggregationExpression` within that package. Then just use that one from there.

Comment: I'm getting closer... this is my implementation:
`public class FilterExpression implements AggregationExpression {
    // private fields and constructor omitted for brevity
    @Override
    public DBObject toDbObject( AggregationOperationContext context ) {
        DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
        filterExpression.put("input", input);
        filterExpression.put("as", as);
        filterExpression.put("cond", cond);
        return new BasicDBObject("$filter", filterExpression);
    }
}`

Comment: The expression seems correct (invoking the toDBObject() and a toJson() produces: "{ "$filter" : { "input" : "$answer_list", "as" : "answer", "cond" : { "$eq2" : ["$$answer.question", 2] } } }") but I'm getting thi exception:
`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property answer found for type Opinion!
 at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
...`

Comment: I get the same exception with this code:
`            project( "answer_list" ).and( "answer_list" ).project( "filter", "$answer_list", "answer",
                            new BasicDBObject("$eq2", Arrays.<Object> asList("$$answer.question", 2)) ),`

Comment: got a bit of code at hand I can run/debug? A gist with a failing testcase maybe?

Comment: I've create a GitHub repository: https://github.com/optimalab/filterExpressionTest
If I've done everything correctly you should just run mvn test

Comment: I'm playing with the demo project... leaving just the project I've successfully run the query by removing the "answer_list" in the project call. Maybe it's a problem related to the double reference to the same field?

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing the code - please try the following for project `project().andInclude(Fields.from(Fields.field("answer_list", "answerList"))).and(expression).as("profile")`. Still the aggregation does not  return any result, but that seems to be another issue as I tried running the snipped in the comment against the test data on the console which also did not return anything.

Comment: The generated query has a problem: the alias for the addInclude is not correct. `{ "$project" : { "answer_list" : "$answer_list"` should be `{ "$project" : { "answerList" : "$answer_list"`

Comment: The cause could be the call `Fields.field("answer_list", "answerList")`. The documentation says the first parameter is the name (alias), the second is the target. Bu if I invert the parameters i get the PropertyReferenceError again

Comment: Digging the code I found something strange in org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath, line 259. There's a splitter on '_' char for looking the existsing properties, so "answer_list" become ["answer", "list"], and then it fails 'cause the field "answer" is not found. Why is there this splitter?

Comment: Ok, I finally solved the issue: you last suggestion was correct. Fields.field("answer_list", "answerList") is right, 'cause the target should be the mapped field name (answerList). Maybe this should be highlighted in the docs? So I had to correct the references in the group section. I updated the git repository for future references. Thanks for your precious help!!

Comment: By resolving [DATAMONGO-1492](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1492) you should be able to directly use `AggregationExpression` as it is `public` now. The change has been applied to: 1.8.5 (Gosling SR5), 1.9.3 (Hopper SR3) and 1.10 RC1 (Ingalls)

Answer (score 4):

There is one more alternative using `Aggregation`

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.valueOf;

    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                               project()
                               .and(filter("answer_list")
                               .as("answer")
                           .by(valueOf("answer.question").equalToValue(2)))
                               .as("profile"));
    AggregationResults<OutputType> profile = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, InputType.class, OutputType.class);
```

I may not be able to answer your question correctly but I just wanted to give another approach for aggregation as there are lesser number of examples using `Aggregation`.

In `project()` you can specify keys you want in your response, as its a varargs method

Comment: I like this answer better. However, please include static imports you are using in your answer. For anyone else, the valueOf() operator comes from here: `import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.valueOf;`

Comment: In the [AggregationTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/4c77763cd39abf2a2d7e199778016728b45d79fc/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationTests.java) class in the spring-data-mongodb repository you'll find more examples. E.g. for for filtering within a project see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/4c77763cd39abf2a2d7e199778016728b45d79fc/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationTests.java#L1686).