# $filter inside $project MongoDB Using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have a subdocument that is an array of a parent document. **"devices"**

In that array I've got a property which is a Date property.

I want to find the parents documents who contains the child subdocuments by determinated date like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5818fa596969a1339093a7da"),
"fecha" : ISODate("2016-11-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
"spot" : "5808e3926969a126c8365c94",
"devices" : [ 
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    }, 
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    },  
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    }, 
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    }, 
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    }, 
    {
        "evaluationDate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z"),
        "seenTimesCounter" : 0,
        "category" : "PRE_PASAJERO",
        "status" : "NO_CONECTADO"
    }
]
}
```

**I have tried this on mongo shell (and the query is good, it Returns what I want):**

```
db.getCollection('spotMovimientos').aggregate([
{$match:{'devices.evaluationDate':ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z")}},
{$project: {
'devices':{$filter:{
    input:'$devices',
    as:'device',
    cond: {$eq: ['$$device.evaluationDate', ISODate("2016-11-01T20:26:00.000Z")]}
    }
} }
}
])
```

Can anyone elaborate on this? I need help to convert this to **SPRING DATA**

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with the Spring boot Version 1.4.1.RELEASE and I did this:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("devices.evaluationDate").is(date)),
            project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
                @Override
                public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                    DBObject filterExpression = new BasicDBObject();
                    filterExpression.put("input", "$devices");
                    filterExpression.put("as", "device");
                    filterExpression.put("cond", new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.<Object> asList("$$device.evaluationDate", date)));
                    return new BasicDBObject("$filter", filterExpression);
                }
            }).as("devices")
    );

    AggregationResults<SpotMovimientos> list = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,
            MyClass.class, MyClass.class);
```

I elaborated based on this: [Does Spring Data MongoDb support $filter array aggregations operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459898/does-spring-data-mongodb-support-filter-array-aggregations-operator)

My project was on Spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE but that version didnt have the **AggregationExpression** interface PUBLIC, so i just updated to 1.4.1.RELEASE and i did work.

Answer (score 8):

And this is how it's made in **spring-data-monogodb-2.0.10** (Spring Boot 2)

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("devices.evaluationDate").is(date)),
                project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                        Document filterExpression = new Document();
                        filterExpression.put("input", "$devices");
                        filterExpression.put("as", "device");
                        filterExpression.put("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.<Object> asList("$$device.evaluationDate", date)));
                        return new Document("$filter", filterExpression);
                    }
                }).as("devices")
        );
```