# Mongodb java driver how to use filter in projection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this query which works fine in mongodb:

```
db.document.aggregate([
{$match: { $and: [ 
    { type:ObjectId('abc') }, 
    { metadata: { $elemMatch: { metadataType: ObjectId("abc"), value: DBRef("tag", ObjectId("abc"))}}},
    { metadata: { $elemMatch: { metadataType: ObjectId("abc"), value: "abc"}}}
    ] }
},
{$project: {
      metadata: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$metadata",
            as: "metadata",
            cond: { $or: [
                {$eq: [ "$$metadata.metadataType", ObjectId("abc") ] },
                {$eq: [ "$$metadata.metadataType", ObjectId("abc") ] }]}
          }
        }
      }
```

How could I do this in JAVA using mongodb driver? I can do the $match stage but I don't know how to do the $project stage using $filter for the array.

I could use Document.parse() (like suggested here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/W4wiPYk0Gec ) but I think it's pretty ugly.
Or I could use something like here: [Does Spring Data MongoDb support $filter array aggregations operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459898/does-spring-data-mongodb-support-filter-array-aggregations-operator) But it's also not too pretty.

Basically my question is: is there a good/better way to do this in the newer versions of mongodb driver? (Something like the 3rd answer here for spring mongodb: [Query a document and all of its subdocuments that match a condition in mongodb (using spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467386/query-a-document-and-all-of-its-subdocuments-that-match-a-condition-in-mongodb) )

***** EDIT

More precisely:
Is there a way to do it like the match part here:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = document.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.match(and(
                                eq("type", new ObjectId("abc")),
                                elemMatch("metadata", and(eq("metadataType", language), eq("value", abc))),
                                elemMatch("metadata", and(eq("metadataType", workClusterName), eq("value", "abc")))
                        )),
                        Aggregates.project(filterHOWTO)
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with spring's `MongoTemplate` using `MongoTemplate#aggregate` and passing it a spring `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` object, which you build via a `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria` builder pattern. The `Criteria` object has methods for `elemMatch`, etc. There are methods in `Criteria` for every aspect of the query you've posted here -- you just need to learn how to chain them together in the `Criteria` builder.