# Project New Array Field with Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

As part of an aggregate operation, I need to unwind an array. I am wondering how I can put the object back into an array as part of the project. Here is the MongoDB aggregate operation that works:

```
db.users.aggregate([ { "$match" : {...} , { "$unwind" : "$profiles"} ,{$project: {'profiles': ['$profiles']}}...}
```

And more specifically, how can I implement this using Spring Data mongoDB ProjectionOperation:

```
{$project: {'profiles': ['$profiles']}}
```

This feature has been added since [3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#new-array-fields).

Edit 1:

I looked through some of the posts and one answer by
[Christoph Strobl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459898/does-spring-data-mongodb-support-filter-array-aggregations-operator/39465971#39465971):

and based on the answer I came up with something that works which is as follows:

```
  AggregationOperation project = aggregationOperationContext -> {
    Document projection = new Document();
    projection.put("profiles", Arrays.<Object> asList("$profiles"));
    projection.put("_id","$id");
    return new Document("$project", projection);
  };
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it though.
Any help/suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.

You can replace `$project` by `project()` with an `AggregationExpression` to shorten it a bit.

```java
// ...
unwind("profiles"), 
project().and(ctx -> new Document("profiles", asList("$profiles"))).as("profiles")
```

I created [DATAMONGO-2312](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2312) to provide support for new array field projections in one of the next versions.

Comment: @Strobl, Sir, you rock. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Strobl, there is a small issue here though. The above code generates an extra 'profile' like this: { "$project" : { "profiles" : { "profiles" : [ "$profiles"] }}}. This is due to using 'as' in the code. I could not find a way around this. Do you know of a way to work around this? Thanks.

Comment: sorry missed that one - and there's no way around it. Snapshot builds for DATAMONGO-2312 are already available if you want to give `project().andArrayOf(...)` a try.

Comment: Wow, That was fast. Will do for sure. Thanks a lot @Christoph.